# Provide an entry for select loop for bash file

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting

How can I provide an entry for selection to give the results, when I run the code in the terminal, it works perfectly, the code is:

```
PS3="Enter the space shuttle to get quick information : "
 
# set shuttle list
select shuttle in columbia endeavour challenger discovery atlantis enterprise pathfinder
do
    case $shuttle in
        columbia)
            echo "--------------"
            echo "Space Shuttle Columbia was the first spaceworthy space shuttle in NASA's orbital fleet."
            echo "--------------"
            ;;
        endeavour)
            echo "--------------"       
            echo "Space Shuttle Endeavour is one of three currently operational orbiters in the Space Shuttle." 
            echo "--------------"       
            ;;
        challenger) 
            echo "--------------"               
            echo "Space Shuttle Challenger was NASA's second Space Shuttle orbiter to be put into service."
            echo "--------------"                   
            ;;      
        discovery) 
            echo "--------------"       
            echo "Discovery became the third operational orbiter, and is now the oldest one in service."
            echo "--------------"                           
            ;;      
        atlantis)
            echo "--------------"       
            echo "Atlantis was the fourth operational shuttle built."
            echo "--------------"                           
            ;;
        enterprise)
            echo "--------------"       
            echo "Space Shuttle Enterprise was the first Space Shuttle orbiter."
            echo "--------------"                           
            ;;      
        pathfinder)
            echo "--------------"       
            echo "Space Shuttle Orbiter Pathfinder is a Space Shuttle simulator made of steel and wood."
            echo "--------------"                           
            ;;
        *)      
            echo "Error: Please try again (select 1..7)!"
            ;;      
    esac
done
```

But when I try to run it in jupyter notebook, it doesn't work, I tried (I also tried the code itself):

```
%%bash
cd /shellfilepath
bash file.sh

cd /shellfilepath
bash file.sh | 1

%%bash
cd /shellfilepath
bash file.sh | echo "1"

%%bash
cd /shellfilepath
if bash file.sh; then echo "1"
```

The output stops at question to enter the selection, which suppose to be 1, the shell file should show me the output of selection 1. What I want is that the shell file read 1 as an entry.

Comment: What's this `bash file.sh | 1` supposed to do? Or `bash file.sh | echo "1"` for that matter? Do you get any errors...?

Comment: I had to search for that _jupyter notebook_ now. Please include basic info about it for others not having to. Thank you.

Comment: @ilkkachu  I was trying to pipe the first action of the bash file to grab number 1 as an input, which is one of the selection number, I tried this because I ran out of ideas.

Comment: So, you are brand new to shell scripting? You should mention this too in order not to get many down-votes. Cheers.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak I updated the code, I'm new to everything...lol. I just learned how to place the code in a code block on stackexchange, I'm learning, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No, no, it's in no way an inconvenience, I just had these thoughts, anyhow time for bed for me now, see you around! | +1

Comment: Maybe you want something like: `echo 1 | bash file.sh`?

Comment: @AndyDalton sorry for the late reply, for some reason I did get a notification about your comment, it worked partially, thank you! I'm still getting some error. Can you put your comment as an answer, I'd like to accept it and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

Your script reads from standard input.  If you want some other process's output to become the standard input to your script, you'll want to use a pipe.

```
$ echo 3 | bash file.sh
1) columbia    3) challenger  5) atlantis    7) pathfinder
2) endeavour   4) discovery   6) enterprise
Enter the space shuttle to get quick information : --------------
Space Shuttle Challenger was NASA's second Space Shuttle orbiter to be put into service.
--------------
Enter the space shuttle to get quick information :
```

Note that your script doesn't know in this case that the input is coming from a file, so it still prints the menu, etc as if it was interacting with a user.